# So... This is a patent for free energy? Or am I missing something here?

Tags: us4151431, magnet, motor

Perpetual energy, to my understanding, is not allowed to be patented - so why this one? It seems to claim a motor that requires no electricity to run. Instead, it uses a magnet formation to create a faux force [US4151431][1].

Comment: While the discussion of a specific product/method may be off topic here, the patent number cited was filed in 1973. Had this been the real thing, our present-day electric cars would be battery-less?

Comment: Perpetual motion machines are not patentable because they fail the "useful" critera. They are considered to have "incredible utility" and the applicant has the burden to prove it is useful. You can get things that spin around for a long time patented as novelty items that are fun to watch go around. At one time heavier that air flight and growing hair were both considered to be incredibe utility. Unless you are curing all cancers or making energy from nothing the examiner will normally take an aplication at face value.